# change id of a form with jQuery but jQuery uses the old attributes to recognize it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that it contents changes every time (for example inbox and sentbox items). I want to change the role of the submit button of the form. I do it this way:

1. first of all when I changing place, I rename the form id which I submit via an ajax request.(`$('#onlist').submit(function ()`)
2. Finally I define a new ajax request based on the new form id.(`$('#onsentlist').submit(function ()`)

But it seems that the second form also uses the old function that I described for the old form id. Why this thing happening? Is there a way to fix it? Or a new solution? Thanks.
here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#onlist').submit(function () {
        var formData = new FormData($('#onlist')[0]);
        $('#res').append("<div id='alertshow' class='alert alert-info'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a><strong></strong>Loading,Please Wait...</div>");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'deletemsg.php',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
              $('#res').empty().append(msg);
              $('form input:checked').parents('a').remove();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
         });
            return false;
        });
    });

     $('#onsentlist').submit(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($('#onsentlist')[0]);
            $('#res').append("<div id='alertshow' class='alert alert-info'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a><strong></strong>Loading,Please Wait...</div>");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'deletesentmsg.php',  //Server script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#res').empty().append(msg);
                    alert('here');
                    $('form input:checked').parents('a').remove();
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            return false;
        });
    $('#refbut').click(function(){
        $('#reload').load('loadmsgs.php');
    });
    $('#sentbox').click(function(){
        $('#reload').load('loadsent.php');
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $('#onlist').attr('id','onsentlist');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('#inbox').click(function(){
        $('#reload').load('loadmsgs.php');
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $('#onsentlist').attr('id','onlist');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<form method="post" id="onlist">
    <button type="submit" id="delbt" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>   
    </button>
    <hr>
    <div id="reload" class="list-group">
        <?php require_once('load.php'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If your renaming IDs I think you've misunderstood the concept of an ID. Perhaps you want `title` or a custom `data` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bind occurs on the actual DOM node. So changing a specific property/attribute of it does not change what is bound on it.
2. The only thing you change in the two hanlders is the url, so it would better to just use a single script that selects the url based on a condition

so

```
$('#onlist').submit(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('#onlist')[0]),
        actionUrl = $(this).data('action-url');

    $('#res').append("<div id='alertshow' class='alert alert-info'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a><strong></strong>Loading,Please Wait...</div>");

    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl ,  //Server script to process data, using the dynamic URL we set
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
          $('#res').empty().append(msg);
          $('form input:checked').parents('a').remove();
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
     });
        return false;
    });
});


$('#sentbox, #inbox').click(function(){
    var url= $(this).data('action-url');

    $('#reload').load('loadsent.php');
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $('#onlist').data('action-url', url);
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
        $parent.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

and on the html add the attribute `data-action-url="deletemsg.php"` and `data-action-url="deletesentmsg.php"` on each button respectively..

Answer (score 1):

Because changing an id of an element does not magically remove the events attached to the element.

You would need to unbind the event.

Second when you bind the event to an element that does not exist, it will not bind anything. It will not attach itself dynamically to the updated element.

You either need to change it so the logic for submmitted and not submitted in one submit function. Or you can bind the second function when you change the id. OR you can use event delegation to do the submission.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should reconsider your approach... An ID is an unique identifier, you shouldn't need to change it at all... But moving on...

The way you assigned the event function

```
$('#onlist').submit(function () {
```

Attachs the listener to the element itself, not to the id targeted... In order to look for the Id at runtime you would need to use an event delegation, targeting a preceding element, like `document`:

```
  $(document).on("submit", "#onsentlist", function () { ...

  $(document).on("submit", "#onlist", function () { ...
```